# Affine vs Yokonuma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory, affine-grassmannian, affine-hecke-algebras

Let $G=GL_n$. Let us start with the Hecke algebra $H_n$. It acts on K(constructible sheaves on $G/B$) by Hecke correpondences and on K(coherent sheaves on $G/B$) by Lusztig's construction [1]. Now we can extend $H_n$ by adding a commutative algebra in two ways.

In the first way we take constructible sheaves, but replace $B$ by $U$. The finite field analogue of the result is the so-called Yokonuma-Hecke algebra, the algebra of double cosets $U(F_q)\G(F_q)/U(F_q)$. It contains the group algebra of the torus $T(F_q)$ and has a surjective map to $H_n$.

In the second way we take coherent sheaves, so we can tensor by line bundles. This way we recover Lusztig's construction [1] of action of the affine Hecke algebra, which is generated by $H_n$ and a commutative subalgebra, which is the algebra of Laurent polynomials in $n$ variables, in other words the group algebra of the character group of the torus $T$.

So, we have two ways to add a commutative algebra to the Hecke algebra. Is there some kind of well-known duality between them and how to see it on the algebra level?

[1]: Lusztig, George. “Equivariant K-Theory and Representations of Hecke Algebras.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 94, no. 2, 1985, pp. 337–342.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure if this is the kind of answer you are looking for, but Chlouveraki in [her thesis](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01411063/document) as well as [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3207.pdf) explains the differences in the two deformations. Generally speaking, in the finite convolution algebra you describe above we have that the additional generators coming from $T(\mathbb{F}_q)$ have finite order $d=|\mathbb{F}_q^\times|$. In particular, the Yokonuma-Hecke algebra deforms the wreath product algebra $S_n\ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z})^n$ in a way that preserves the wreath product structure but deforms the quadratic Hecke relations.

In some sense an orthogonal deformation of these wreath products is given by the cyclotomic Hecke/Ariki-Koike algebras, which are quotients of the affine Hecke algebra. In these the Hecke relations are preserved but the wreath product structure is deformed instead. The finite Hecke algebra for $GL_n$ embeds naturally inside the Ariki-Koike algebras, but is naturally a quotient of the Yokonuma-Hecke algebras.

Additionally, you could do both deformations at the same time to arrive at cyclotomic and affine Yokonuma-Hecke algebras as in work of Chlouveraki and Poulain d'Andecy.

As to the actual question about a duality between Yokonuma-Hecke and the affine Hecke algebra, I don't know. Geometrically, one might suspect something like it based on Bezrukavnikov-Yun. Also, Weideng Cao has some purely algebraic work proving that the Yokonuma-Hecke algebra is isomorphic to a tensor product of (matrix algebras over) cyclotomic Hecke algebras.

Comment: I was suspecting something like Bezrukavnikov-Yun should be there, and I am still hoping that someone can explain it